# How to intrepret one significant and one insignificant mediator and a significant direct effect in PROCESS?

Tags: spss, mediation, psychometrics

I have conducted a mediation analysis with two mediators using PROCESS.

My findings are that in X -- a --> M1 -- b --> Y, a and b are significant.

However in X -- c --> M2 -- d --> Y, only d is significant while c is not.

Moreover X --> Y is significant in the mediation model, but not in the Total Effect Model.

What can I make from these findings? I am a little stuck and would appreciate your help! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Looks like you have a partial parallel mediation model. By partial mediation, it is meant that X (the antecedent) affects Y (the outcome variable) both through each mediator (M1 and M2), as well as directly (X->Y). By parallel, it is meant that you are testing two mediators at once in parallel (which by the way can be either complementary or competitive: see [this paper](http://watermark.silverchair.com/37-2-197.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAmwwggJoBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJZMIICVQIBADCCAk4GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMy3ttD6_0g4BqytmUAgEQgIICH1s5IJaQ2j90r6O38sT5SjqBuPqu36ImX3PkOgyY8iSycFTXbfwX8mbpQSYDQdHW1uPwVJVrsi9725dwScnxq9vX_vyZgz9nkEyr-pPQHsMge2bVBr-xrBwcRgZBZ0nmLXdlJhPN5XBxgZ2LkyLy-9YgBkrtVwCbRzVPLW4VbsisAT-73reBE4rOEW66B0SOvOBHpUkjx50L4Jd2-L8r8P5NzDIFvYlmgG4X_rfqTCuBtwmdCjI1MreQYCkzY0tP2UrQTUr1MFG7Trbvj_ki9pfBTcrPAhRkQPCT2TSkUVMaf59CXz9E4B9IT39uvSgEhIFBEGJL6hGs2vVrUXQUgO3aZYKLg0247k2NLaUZ1aptanqtYvS-BDMKl2W8FvlN4-Quj7UKtDZ5EFlCllhwHsWHAjKWADEiX9fP-_1QWryAwkfJE3BGJjfUN3TAphJp3GTpNn7K-26vHP7t4MKOtSp5QMrw68xrlTUy02rvZHAf6LXlNXLbrPfRQY6aEnfYVNn082zfmhIhvhgpBMpngw2_SxoEq81xMRLXlhKkzNkX7bu5D_grjRD-PGOytMk-cGA8r3F8a99BkTZmFMq_02EnHxqOXiKi-s21SxvFGk7h0zN3C6plfP9D9YsnK0B5Mbqefx3yZurzwaRsXlQMMF5ZWR2KRVY2GweuSFN2woVSh3cVBqevEVZEzHxlxiyTjFr-7XaVZ0ukmXw_SyF2-A) by **Zhao et al (2010)** with 5,000+ citations for more details).
- Now, consider X -> M1 -> Y; and X -> Y mediation first. For this part of the model, you can conclude that there is partial mediation if both the indirect effect (the `a*b` term), and the direct effect (X -> Y, let's call it `z`) are both significant. If only `a*b` term is significant but `z` is not, you have the case of full mediation. Finally, if the `a` path is non-significant, there is no mediation even is the direct effect `z` is significant.
- The same logic can be applied to another part of the model (X -> M2 -> Y; X -> Y). So, I would describe both of these parts of the model in turn.
- At last, your total effect is essentially the effect of X on Y through both mediators (M1 and M2) and the direct effect (X -> Y). So you can see that in its calculation all paths are included. Unless you are specifically interested in the total effect of X on Y (which takes all paths into account simultaneously), I would not usually reporting it. Commenting on each mediation (through M1 and M2) usually suffices.

---

**References**

Zhao, X., Lynch Jr, J. G., & Chen, Q. (2010). Reconsidering Baron and Kenny: Myths and truths about mediation analysis. Journal of Consumer Research, 37(2), 197-206.